# Cannot install mongoose using npm install

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, npm-install

I am trying to npm install mongoose but this error keeps popping up. I have a node.js, express framework and i have added mongoonse in my dependencies in package.json as following,

```
  {
    "name": "OAuthProject",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./bin/www"
       },
   "dependencies": {
     "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
     "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
     "debug": "~2.2.0",
     "express": "~4.13.1",
     "jade": "~1.11.0",
     "morgan": "~1.6.1",
     "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
     "cookie-parser": "latest",
     "express-session": "latest",
     "mongoose": "latest"           //<------------ MONGOOSE
     }
  }
```

I have installed cookie-parser and other modules the same way and those worked. But mongoose and mongodb are not working. Any help is highly appreciated. Below is my log on my terminal. Also, it says to run as a root admin. What might be the command line for that? Sudo apt-get... Thanks!

[image: log]

Comment: Please share more details about the error you're facing, like the output **in text form**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to install as root as it is not getting permission to create directories

you can use `sudo npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sudo npm`.

You can fix this problem follow this [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm cache clean` before installing mongoose. Tested on windows 7