# Can anyone help to solve this

Tags: javascript, mongodb, npm, mongoose

```
PS F:\SCALER\NODE JS\Module1\mongoose> npm install mongoose
npm ERR! code EPERM   
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path F:\     
npm ERR! errno -4048  
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'F:\'     
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'F:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'F:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-28T11_14_21_900Z-debug-0.log
PS F:\SCALER\NODE JS\Module1\mongoose>
```

Not able to install mongoose in this particular folder

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to create a folder called `F:`

Comment: Could you please explain how to solve this

Comment: Grant write permission to this folder

Answer (score 0):

1. Please refer to a similar case, it answers admin access is required.
   [Cannot install mongoose using npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884609/cannot-install-mongoose-using-npm-install)

The diagnostic output displayed in your own case has some useful hints as well.

2. **Try it with admin account** : npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
   npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
   npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
3. **Check log about the issue** : npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-28T11_14_21_900Z-debug-0.log
   PS F:\SCALER\NODE JS\Module1\mongoose>

Thanks

WeDoTheBest4You